# How to strip braces out of Java string?

Tags: java, regex, string

My Java app will be getting strings of the following form:

```
How now [[brown cow ]]. The arsonist [[ had oddly shaped ]] feet. The [[human torch was denied]] a bank loan.
```

And need a regex/method that would strip out every instance of `[[ ]]` (and all inclusive text), thus turning the above string into:

```
How now. The arsonist  feet. The  a bank loan.
```

Notice the preserved double-spaces (between `arsonist` and `feet`, and between `The` and `a`)? That's important too.

Not sure if a regex here is appropriate or if there is a more efficient way of culling out the unwanted `[[ ]]` instances.

Comment: @NilsH String.replace How ?

Comment: @NilsH with String.replace it is hard to remove the part inside the brackets. Regex seems the way to go.

Comment: What is the expected behavior for `[[ something [good] or may be [[ not so good]]`

Answer (score 3):

This is in javascript.

```
var text = "How now [[brown cow ]]. The arsonist [[ had oddly shaped ]] feet. The [[human torch was denied]] a bank loan."
text.replace(/\[\[[^\]]+\]\]/g, "")
```

The regex to match the braces will be

```
/\[\[[^\]]+\]\]/g
```

So Java equivalent will be

```
text.replaceAll("\[\[[^\]]+\]\]", "");
```

and replace it with an empty string

regex which can remove both double and triple braces

```
text.replaceAll("\[?\[\[[^\]]+\]\]\]?", "")
```

Comment: @defaultlocale seems like Javascript :p

Comment: @Pankaj OP question was in java

Comment: Thanks @Pankaj (+1) - please see my comment under MikeM's answer - I have the same question for you!

Comment: @DirtyMikeAndTheBoys edited the answer, here again, this is desired regex `"\[?\[\[[^\]]+\]\]\]?"`

Answer (score 2):

This is simple with `replaceAll`

```
str = str.replaceAll( "\\[\\[[^\\]]*\\]\\]", "" );
```

Assumes no `]` between the brackets.

Comment: Thanks @MikeM (+1) - and what if I have some instances of triple braces (`[[[ ]]]`) - does this same regex apply or do I have to change it? Thanks again!

Answer (score 2):

Try using this code :

```
public class Test{
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String input = "How now [[brown cow ]]. The arsonist [[ had oddly shaped ]] feet. The [[human torch was denied]] a bank loan.";
    // Will replace all data within braces []
    String replaceAll = input.replaceAll("(\\[.+?\\])|(\\])", "");
    System.out.println(replaceAll);
}
```

}

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks @Ankur (+1) - please see my comment under MikeM's answer - I have the same question for you!

Comment: Yes @DirtyMikeAndTheBoys - the code that I have give you will work fine. :-) Let me know, if you need anything else.

Comment: @MikeM - It will work fine for all the combinations. I have tested it as well. Try it once.

Answer (score 2):

```
tring s = "How now [[brown cow ]]. The arsonist [[ had oddly shaped ]] feet. The [[human torch was denied]] a bank loan.";

s=s.replaceAll("\\[.*?\\]","").replace("]","");
```

Output:

```
How now . The arsonist  feet. The  a bank loan.
```

Comment: Thanks @Achintya Jha (+1) - please see my comment under MikeM's answer - I have the same question for you!